# What's the best way to create items like headers with navigation items that are "always on page" in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, architecture

Standard ASP.NET approach for headers seems to be to use Master Pages but these are really just templates for a Page so if I move from ContentPage1 to ContentPage2 I'm just redrawing my navigation header. This doesn't appear to be what sites like Facebook do: their header is genuinely always there using AJAX. Thoughts on best AJAX architectural approach in an MS environment to creating sites like FB?

Comment: Use MVC or Web API, with SPA frameworks like Angular or Durandal.

Comment: Cheers Schabse: exactly the pointer I needed. I've got a load of existing Web Forms pages and am a complete SPA virgin. Is it an either/or decision i.e. do I need to abandon my Web Forms or can I create like a Smaller Number of Pages Application by using Web API & framework selectively. Cheers